# JS/Jquery/RegEx - Remove all tags except the ones with classname XYZ

Tags: regex, class, tags

this is driving me nuts ;-) I have a string whith various span tags... I want to remove all span tags except the ones with classname XYZ... The problem is that i havent found a solution to leave the closing tag...

My starting point is this regex:

```
 text = text.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

But everything i tried to say "DONT DO IT IF MATCH classnameXYZ Failed till now...

Any ideas? **Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works for my needs ;-)

```
                $('#text > span').each(function(intIndex){
                    var word;
                    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
                        word = "<span>"+$(this).html()+"</span>";
                    } else {
                        word = $(this).html();
                        word = word.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
                    }
                    console.log(word);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with out a regular expression, more over your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690549/js-jquery-regex-remove-all-tags-except-the-ones-with-classname-xyz/3690591#3690591) need to cache the entire html, which would be slow, try the below code, It may help :)

```
$(function()
    $('#text > span').each(function() {
       if(!$(this).hasClass('XYZ')) { 
           $(this).remove();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: In your question `Remove all tags except the ones with classname XYZ` what do u mean by Remove all tags ?? Doesn't it refer to remove entire element ?